# how can I change string character where I had known index?

Tags: python, string

in Python,I have a string like "MARINE" and I must change A to M and M to A. I know A[1] is "A" and A[0] is "M" but I can't `A[0] = A[1]` (overwriting isn't allowed) so I think I can use `replace` but I failed .What can I do ?

Comment: strings are immutable in python

Comment: it s mean ı have to rewriting all char to another string.

Comment: Yes, you have to make a new string

Comment: As indexes are known, you may try this: `strvar = strvar[1] + strvar[0] + strvar[2:]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a translation table.

```
>>> table = str.maketrans("AM", "MA")
>>> "MARINE".translate(table)
"AMRINE"
```

`maketrans` is a convenience function for creating a table where most characters are mapped to themselves. Here, we're mapping `A` to `M`, `M` to `A`, and leaving everything else alone. The `translate` method uses this table to replace each character in the `str` object using the character specified by the given table.

[Documentation for both `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) can be found in the Python documentation. `maketrans`, in particular, provides several ways to build a translation table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use traditional `for` loop

```
s = "MARINE"
new_s = ""

for i in s:
    if i == "M":
        new_s = new_s + "A"
    elif i == "A":
        new_s = new_s + "M"
    else:
        new_s = new_s + i

print(new_s)
```

Comment: Note that this is a quadratic-time solution, given that you are repeatedly creating a near-copy of the string in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable you used to store your strin is called A then this would work.
A.replace("MA", "AM")

Comment: This will only work when the string has "MA", what if the string is "AMRINE"?